# Не могу получить информацию посредством API

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Есть статистика соц.сети Вконтакте ,ссылка у каждого своя
Пример:

```
> https://vk.com/stats?act=activity&mid=USERID
```

Во вкладке активность есть такая инфа
"683 человека подписались на уведомления"
Вопрос, как добыть эту информацию методом API или любым иным способом?
метод `Stats.get` с параметром Users_ID выдает только статистику,
выяснил что так же есть Mini-APP `vk.com/app6836678` получал токен
от этого приложения и так же запрашивал `execute.StatsGet` с разными
параметрами, выдает только основную информацию, так вот вопросы:
Есть ли способы выгружать информацию о приложении по токену(androidVK,VKME)?
Есть ли другой способ открыть эту страницу посредством логин:пароль?
**Прошу помощи у тех кто сталкивался с VK_API , и парсингом инфы с данной соц.сети!**

Answer (score 0):

вопрос у вас сформулировал не корректно. что вам нужно сделать? авторизоваться в vk_api по логин:пароль?

это можно сделать через сайт  [vkhost.github.io](https://vkhost.github.io/)
далее парусите данные через наиболее удобные для вас методы vk_api

Comment: Вопрос, как получить именно эту цифру из статистики, или как получить страницу приложения посредством токена. В документации такого нет, но в смартфоне и на сайте зайти в эту статистику можно и увидеть эту самую цифру кол-ва подписанных на обновления.

Comment: Никак нельзя. В случае с уведомлениями - никто кроме тебя не имеет данной информации, в мобильном приложение тоже не видел. В случае с «порекомендовавшими» - видно только друзьям